# How do I convert a dictionary with array values containing nested lists into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary containing an array of nested lists, where each dictionary key references a unique array.  It outputs like this:

```
{'pop.2.q': array([[11.07967784],
   [11.07967784],
   [11.07967785],
   ...,
   [11.16404993],
   [11.16404993],
   [11.16404993]]), 'pop.2.v': array([[0.00011533],
   [0.00011533],
   [0.00011533],
   ...,
   [0.00014513],
   [0.00014513],
   [0.00014513]]), 'propagator.1.phi': array([[0.],
   [0.],
   [0.],
   ...,
   [0.],
   [0.],
```

I'm trying to convert it into a pandas dataframe, where each dictionary key (ie. 'pop.2.q', 'pop.2.v', etc) is a column.  Right now, my dataframe looks like this with the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[Res.data], index=Res.time)
```

[current df output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6X19.png)

Any help with how to unpack this and properly populate the df would be super appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all values in dictionary are lists with same number of (flattened) items, this should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict([(x,np.array(list(y)).flatten()) for x,y in d.items()]))
```

assuming d is your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When using this, its raising: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'flatten'.  Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I thought your array was a numpy array. In case it's a pd.Series you could cast it into a numpy array. I have just updated my answer. See the updated version above.